# for loops in python with cointer

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcJEc.jpg)how do I make this code index position 2-1 next time round then index position 3-2 and so on and so on

```py
for x in stock_df['Normed Return']:
    stock_df['daily diff'] = stock_df.iloc [1]['Normed Return'] - stock_df.iloc [0]['Normed Return']
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your code is doing, but something like `for i in range(1, length)` should work. Just use `i` and `i-1` as the indexes. Or maybe you'd want to use `enumerate`? not sure.

Comment: have you tried `df['daily diff'] = df['Normed Return'] - df['Normed Return'].shift()`

Comment: I'm trying to go back to the previous day and see diff in stock price percent - I'm doing it by using .iloc[1]['Normed Return'] - .iloc[0]['Normed Return'] then trying to loop through .iloc[2]['Normed Return'] - .iloc[1]['Normed Return']

Answer (score 1):

got answer, sorry, it was real easy actually

```
stock_df['daily per change'] = stock_df['Normed Return'].pct_change(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

To iterate an iterable in a pairwise manner, you can use, well, [`pairwise` from itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)


daily_diffs = []
for day_a, day_b in pairwise(stock_df.iloc):
    daily_diffs.append(day_b['Normed Return'] - day_a['Normed Return'])
```